# how to select elements based on one attribute and excluding those with another attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors

I'm stuck here:

I want to select all divs with attribute *data-role="page"* which do not carry an *data-internal-page="true"* attribute.

This does not work:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').not('div:jqmData(internal-page="true")')
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong in the syntax? The 2nd attribute is always disregarded.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is it data-internal-page? if so then shouldn't it be div:jqmData(data-internal-page="true").

Comment: jquery-mobile uses jqmData(some="thing"), which will result in data-some="thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use `jqmData` but it is possible that it doesn't look-up all `data-attribute`s but only the ones associated with jQuery Mobile. Try using regular attribute selectors:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').not('div[data-internal-page="true"]')
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4mxw/

Note that your selectors will run faster if you don't use the tagName:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').not('[data-internal-page="true"]')
```

Comment: I thought about that, too but I also get 6 out of 6 divs returned, where it should only be 1. Also, your expression firebugs to: uncaught exception: Syntax error

Comment: I left a colon in the second selector which is now fixed in my example, try the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4mxw/

Comment: yup. also works. thx. Since i prefer .not over :not... you get the nod :-)

Comment: Using the function equivalent in jQuery is almost always faster than using a pseudo selector. `$('ul li a')` is slower than `$('ul').children('li').find('a')` and `$('a:not(".some-class")')` is slower than `$('a').not('.some-class')`. Every time I've tested the performance difference I find that using functions is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with *native* jquery (without any selector plugin/extension):

```
var $divs = $('div[data-role="page"]:not([internal-page="true"])');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/PHyyD/)**

Comment: nope. also 6. but I found out what was wrong... I'm calling before the other script assigned data-internal-page

Comment: sorry. i have 6 div elements altogether, 5 of which have the 2nd attribute and should not be included in the selection.

Comment: Well the selector works, it's just, as you describe, a problem with your attributes not set.

Answer (score 0):

Timing... I was calling the selector correclty, but before the 2nd attribute was assigned. Setting a timeout like so showed this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log( $('div:jqmData(role="page")').not('div:jqmData(internal-page="true")').length );       
    },500);
```

Thanks for help everybody!